# Dynamic Typecasting for getters and setters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, javabeans

I need a logic for a problem, Imagine we have a bean with 50 properties, with getters and setters in it, While updating a bean object I have to write many getters and setters statements, I need a logic to get and set values in a loop. I know I have to downcast it but, the downcasting should be dynamic.

In simple words I need a method which accepts any type object and typecast to get all its properties

```
class ExampleGetterSetter {

   public <T> T getSet(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
      // Object obj1, obj2 should be dynamically typecasted to get its properties,
      // I dont want to use instance of operator here
      // this will reduce great lines of code in my project
   }

}
```

Comment: Seems like you're looking for **reflection**: [The Java™ Tutorials - The Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

Comment: _Why_ do you need to get and set all these values? It smells like you're reinventing something that already exists.

Comment: Use lombok.https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what's your problem. If you have a very big bean, and you want to set its properties in a loop, the key is what's the data source?

If the data source is a map or list of entry like sturct data, You can use reflection to iterate over the properties of the bean, and use reflection to set it.

If the data source is another bean or even the same bean, the reflection is still a choice.

In fact, there has exist a famous library [commons-beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) which can help you do all the thing above.

On the other hand. If you have a very big bean, and want to create a similar bean, you can use my library [beanknife](https://github.com/vipcxj/beanknife). It's a tool to generate the class from another class, and provide the converter method in it. For example

```
class Bean {
   // many many properties.
}

@ViewOf(value = Bean.class, includePattern = ".*")
class BeanDtoConfiguration {
}
```

Then will generate a such class

```
class BeanView {
   // many properties same with Bean

   // the converter method.
   public static BeanView read(Bean bean) {
       ...
   }
}
```